# Dealing with coworker who always blames others

Tags: work-environment, software-development

I am a QA of 10 developers and we have a new developer who has been troubling me for 5 months.

Every bug I assign to him I always get complaints from him. Then when he sees one bug he would tell fellow developer that I never tested the app. There is one issue that was raised a few months ago and was logged as a bug but it remained open for further investigation. The environment was changed and it resolved the issue - but the issue is still open for the same reason. He again said this was never tested.

This bothers me so much as I had been very diligent with my tests and this guy has always been spoonfed and shows no accountability or no interest in resolving a bug. He dodges the issue and blames it on the QA.

How can I approach this situation in a professional way?

I have already talked with my boss about this but since he is under probationary and well, legal terms, he tries to give this person a chance. He gets the chance but he still tears the QA down.

Comment: "under probationary and well, legal terms" -- Is he already working under  PIP?

Comment: What i meant was since he is only 5 months in the organization, my boss gives a chance or time for him to adapt to our culture.

Comment: My boss isn't a QA Manager. He won't blame it on me. The new guy does.. all the freaking time..

Comment: Did you show him your test case, test execution and results to prove to him that it was tested? Possibly in the future you can add this on your bug tracking tool with screenshots as 'proof'. This is what I did when one of the Developers wouldn't believe me also. If there was problem further than that, you should let your QA manager deal with it. Possibly go to their Dev Manager and find a way to deal with him.

Comment: Too bad I have no QA Manager since I am the only QA in the team :D but yes all of my documentations are in place, bug details were detailed very carefully. Test cases are also documented. Screenshots are in place as well.

Comment: There was one time I had to modify the data in the database and my point was, if this is a non admin or regular user, it should not be able to do that.He should put a restriction on the user I was using. He went on to me and argued saying this scenario is never valid because I am just a tester :D

Comment: "hen he sees one bug he would tell fellow developer that I never tested the app" - don't you have log files? With time stamps?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should leave it to your boss to sort out. There is nothing you can do that has no chance of backfiring on you and this is managements role. If the boss is aware of it and the guys review is coming up, it will be taken care of then. Best for you if it was earlier but life's not always fair.

Just keep your back covered and ignore anything unprofessional.

Comment: My fear is the guy would still be employed with us after 6 months and he would be more complacent about himself. My boss let's us manager ourselves which we could really do it as our team is fairly independent. When he came in, things changed. Work environment became negative on me.

Comment: _"Work environment became negative on me."_ - What does that mean exactly? @Marj

Comment: @Marj Are you saying that other people have turned against you as well?

Comment: I'm sorry, my work environment has become negative to me. Improper usage of 'on'. Non Native speaker here :)

Answer (score 1):

This depends a bit on your organisational structure, but I see it a bit as a responsibility of the whole team to get a new one on board.

What you are describing sounds a bit destructive, and you should absolutely try to get to a constructive work environment. So the first question is: As you are a team of 10, are you two the only ones having the problems with each other or does the whole team have issues.

If it is especially you he seems to have picked you out, just seek a personal conversation to turn this productive - he probably just feels threatened or belittled by you, finding his bugs.

If it is a team-thing, you could try to become his sponsor and help him to adjust.

Sure, it is always the safer way to step back, cover your ass, and let management deal with another failed attempt at employing someone. But there is a big reward in being able to turn such a colleague into an happy and productive one! Also, you can not save all of them, some just don´t want to grow into a job, so bother when you think there is potential.

Comment: Of all the developers i dealt with, this is the only guy who is having a problem. My boss has a trust on me, maybe I need to adjust more on him being stricter now than how he was before.i tried to reach out to the person but he says different stuff in front of me and destructive stuff at my back.

Comment: Ok ,but is he especially hostile towards you, or are your teammates experiencing the same difficulties?

Comment: My project leader had the same issues. He comes off as really great with the developers because developers don't care really what he does as we have our own projects to sort out.

Comment: _"My project leader had the same issues."_ Your lead had the same issues with you or with Mr "NewGuy" ?

Comment: I don´t think being stricter will help - only escalate faster.
Either he can´t do better -> get rid of him. Or he does not want to do better - then the problem probably lies somewhere in the communication. Find out why and you can probably solve it.

Comment: @Fildor my project leader has the same issues with the new guy. I'm sorry for the confusion..

Comment: He is slow in terms of understanding how things work in the team. I am not a developer but I had been telling him to check on correct UI - DB environments, debug the code, or ask someone who knows the project better. He won't. So, I do the job that he should do because he is hesitant to reach out. I have no idea why. My teammates are the most approachable people in the world but he won't take that advantage.

Comment: Some dev´s also have an attitude to not bother about bugs - that´s what QA is for, right? ... If that is the case here, maybe someone needs to set him straight so maybe being strict could help. Let me quote out of Robert C. Martin´s "The Clean Coder": QA should find nothing. Maybe he should read that?

Comment: I was thinking it is his some sort of defense mechanism - our team is so agile - he complained that our team is very slow - when it is not. Most of us work with 3-5 projects at the same time. He works with one project and mostly is assisted by 2 or 3 people